# Need to remove the border on text

Tags: html, css

I have this jsfiddle that shows my current code but it doesn't serve me well. I want to remove the border that strikes my text

Need to have something like -------- Some text -------

Also need the whole border top, bottom, left and right and the background color yellow should remain intact, I understand applying a border white will do it but I don't want to show a white background for the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/1yb6jt1k/2/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="testing">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Some text but the border cuts it</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>





.testing{
    margin:50px auto;
    background:transparent;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:10px;
}

.testing li{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
.testing li > label{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

Comment: You can try to remove that line: margin-top: -20px;. Hope it will help.

Comment: Why `margin-top: -20px;`?

Comment: Without that margin, the text is aligned inside the li label... I want it to move up

Comment: I want the text to be on the border... Anyone downvoting please give a reason

Comment: See my updated fiddle, I have a background as yellow, so applying the #fff color will show up as white background which I don't want

Comment: By using `legend` element: http://jsfiddle.net/hgchb7je/

Comment: @Vohuman, can you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be easily achieved by using `fieldset` and `legend` elements:

```
<div class="testing">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Some text but the border cuts it</legend>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

[Here is a deme.](http://jsfiddle.net/hgchb7je/)

Answer (score 1):

I understand there is no easy way to do that. But you can use `fieldset` html tag. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gozL5y51/)

Comment: Sorry Vikash, Vohuman had answered this first, but I can give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution? Using a pseudo-class and position it so it covers the line?

http://jsfiddle.net/kidkie/1yb6jt1k/4/

```css
body {
    background-color : yellow;
}
.testing{
    margin:50px auto;
    background:transparent;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:10px;
}

.testing li{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
.testing li > label{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}

.testing li > label span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.testing li > label:before {
    content: "";
    background: yellow;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="testing">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <label for="name"><span>Some text but the border cuts it</span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```